# Defining fluid width with position absolute

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to design a site with a fixed side panel and scrolling content area. The side panel will hold the branding and main navigation - I want this to stay fixed so the nav bar is always visible. I want the hover effect on the menu items to reach the content area. At the moment they spill over because of position: absolute. I understand that assigning this takes it out of the document flow.

[This is a very rough mock up](http://www.bazzadonboy.co.uk/test/)

I know that if I define a width on the left panel and on the ul I can solve this issue but the site needs to be responsive so I really need to keep this fluid.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
header {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

section {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background: white;
    padding: 0 2em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't make difference to the width of the element or even the list element for that matter.